# How to get all tablecell values from a dynamic table using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamic table, it contains 5 textbox controls, i am trying to retrieve label text of all controls. How can i do this.

THanks.

What i had tried:

```
 var table = document.getElementById("ControlTable_");
  if (table != null) {
                    var trlength = table.rows.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < trlength; i++) {
                        var tclenght = table.cells.length;
                        for (var j = 0; j < tclenght; j++) {
                            var check = table.rows[i].cells[j].innerText;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Here i am getting innertext undefined

Comment: please, specify where `UIControlsWizard` comes from, it looks like a raw template... and I suppose jQuery operates on the actual rendered html!

Comment: Please check now @Hitmands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a 2d representation of your table by using something like the following function:

```js
const mapTo = (element, selector, callback) => Array.from(
  element.querySelectorAll(selector),
  callback
);

const extractText = td => td.textContent;

const tableAsJson = mapTo(
  document, 
  '#ControlTable_ tr', 
  (row) => mapTo(row, 'td', extractText),
);

console.log('table', tableAsJson);
```

```html
<table id="ControlTable_">
  <tr>
    <td>hello</td>
    <td>World</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

if your `td` elements also contain something like

```html
<label for="something">
  Label
</label>

<input />
```

then something like this may help

```
const extractText = td => td.querySelector('label').textContent;
```

Just a note, 
please make sure you attach relevant part of your dom structure while asking similar questions in future :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've tried:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("ControlTable_");

if (table != null) {
  var trlength = table.rows.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < trlength; i++) {
    // use this instead of table.cells, because each cell must be specified by a row
    // i.e: table.rows[i].cells
    var td = table.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
      var check = table.rows[i].cells[j].innerText;
      console.log(check);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find and get value from the label in the table cell.

```
var table_rows = $('#ControlTable_ tr');

for (var i = 0; i < table_rows.length; i++) {
    var row = table_rows[i];
    var columns = $(row).find('td');

    for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
        var label = $(columns[j]).find('label');

        if (label.length > 0) {
            var check = label[0].innerText;
            console.log(check);
        }
    }
}
```

Check below link for working example.
https://jsfiddle.net/rgehlot99/d5zntL6c/2/
(Values can be found in console)